# Make numerator and denominator terms of \frac bigger

Tags: equations, fractions

Is there a way to make `\frac{}{}` bigger? By default looks like all equations keep the same size. That means if I write `x=\frac{a}{b}` x has the right size, while frac is a little bit smaller. I want that `x`, numerator and denominator keep the same size.

[image]

Comment: `\dfrac`, from `amsmath`, perhaps?

Comment: Are you using inline math or display math?  Can you provide a compilable example that shows what you mean?

Comment: If not using `amsmath`, one can add `\displaystyle` prior to the invocation of `\frac`.  Note that for inline math, this will likely alter the natural line spacing of the text.

Comment: For inline maths, a solution is to use the `\mfrac` (medium-sized fraction, ca 80 % of display style) command, from `nccmath` and add to the preamble something like `setstretch{1.1}`.

Comment: I used `\dfrac` and I like that. Other solutions without load package and without force me to modify every equation (like using `\displaystyle` )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your document is in inline math mode when the fraction occurs.

- While in inline math mode, the numerator and denominator of `\frac` are set in `\scriptstyle` by default. Script-size letters and symbols are about 30% (linearly) smaller than in text size.
- To force TeX to typeset the numerator and denominator terms in `\textstyle`, either prefix the `\displaystyle` directive to `\frac` or -- if the `amsmath` package is loaded -- write `\dfrac`.
- If you want to typeset the numerator and denominator terms in `\displaystyle` (which may be necessary if you have "large" math symbols such as `\sum` and `\prod`), it's best to set up a dedicated macro called, say, `\ddfrac` to perform the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \dfrac macro
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}}
\newcommand\numer{\sigma_{\mathit{tot}}}
\newcommand\denom{\omega\epsilon_0}
\begin{document}  
$\epsilon''=\frac{\numer}{\denom}$,              %\frac
$\epsilon''=\displaystyle\frac{\numer}{\denom}$, %\displaystyle\frac
$\epsilon''=\dfrac{\numer}{\denom}$,             %\dfrac
$\epsilon''=\ddfrac{\numer}{\denom}$             %\ddfrac
\end{document}
```

Comment: I loaded  `amsmath` and works perfectly. What if I don't wanna load that and I don't wanna modify every equation in my document with `\displaystyle`?

Comment: @Shika93 - Two comments: First, you could create your own macro, called (say) `\mydfrac`, as `\newcommand\mydfrac[2]{{\displaystyle\frac{#1}{#2}}}`. Second, I can honestly not think of a good reason for not wishing to load `amsmath` in a LaTeX document.

Comment: I thought it was useless (I had no idea what `amsmath` does), but now I found out that I need it for other reasons. I have zero knowledge of LaTeX; I started write the thesis a week ago. Thanks!